# How to install Messenger Lite on Samsung tablet

Tags: installation, facebook-messenger, compatibility

I'm want to install Facebook Messenger Lite on my non-rooted Samsung T-580 tablet with Nougat 7.0. There is a message saying:

"Your device isn't compatible with this version."

No more info is provided on why this happens. Why can't I install the application, and is there a way around it?

Comment: Try the solution of download from Amazon https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD8nM5AhJBxAPA/?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

You can install it from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/messenger-lite/messenger-lite-3-1-release/facebook-messenger-lite-3-1-android-apk-download/) choose your android version and it's done. If after installation app misbehave try to install a lower version of the app.

Remember: You may be asked to enable 'Unknown Sources' (to install apps that are downloaded outside of playstore).

To enable:
• Open Settings
• Security Settings

Under 'Security Settings' you will see this option.

[image: Unknown Sources]